# ion-datetime cannot work with MMDD format

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework

I am trying to have a component ion-datetime to have only MMDD format, I do not need the year, but ngModel is not updating the value in ts.

code in html:

```
<ion-datetime name="myDate" id="myDate" [(ngModel)]="myDate" displayFormat="MMDD" pickerFormat="MM DD" [pickerOptions]="customDateOptions"></ion-datetime>
```

code in ts:

```
myDate: string;
someMethod(){
     console.log(myDate); // here myDate is still empty it does not matter if in the view I have already set a value
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with onChange event?

Comment: onChange event does work, I will post as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Ionic is not able to handle correctly MMDD, for this reason the workaround/solution, is to use onChange event as Koga said, but in ionic this is ionChange like following:

```
<ion-datetime #myDatePicker name="myDate" id="myDate" (ionChange)="setMyDate(myDatePicker.value)" displayFormat="MMDD" pickerFormat="MMDD"></ion-datetime>
```

and on typescript:

```
myDate: string;

setMyDate(myDate: DateTimeData): void {
    this.myDate = ''+ myDate.month + myDate.day; //to have as an string MMDD
}
```